# Animation of VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, animation

I am stuck with creating animation of vector plot. My example code is simple

```
myField[x_, y_, t_] := {0, 100*Sin[2*Pi*50*t]*Cos[Pi*y]};
Animate[VectorPlot[myField[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, 0, 2/50}]
```

It is working nicely, except that vectors are rescaled every timestep. Result can be seen in gif animation.

[image]

I found [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96288/color-vectors-according-to-a-user-defined-function), and came up with code

```
With[{vectorscale = {0, 100}, time = 0.08}, 
 Legended[VectorPlot[myField[x, y, time], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, 
   VectorColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
     ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", vectorscale}][Abs[myField]]], 
   VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
   VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorPoints -> 25, 
   AspectRatio -> 1], 
  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", vectorscale}], 
    vectorscale}]]]
```

As you see, this one is not animation, but attempt to create fixed time plot with controllable color scaling. Unfortunately I am missing something very basic, because it does not work at all, I cannot even understand this result:

[image]

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changes:

- added Animate
- `Dynamic` on `VectorPlot` to not recreate Legend at each step
- `VectorColorFunction` should be applied to the 5th argument `n` which is a norm of your field, not to the `field` function. You can square it if you need `Abs` though.

---

```
With[{vectorscale = {0, 100}}, 
 Animate[Legended[
   Dynamic@VectorPlot[myField[x, y, time], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, 
     VectorColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
       ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", vectorscale}][n]], 
     VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorPoints -> 15, 
     AspectRatio -> 1], 
   BarLegend[{ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", vectorscale}], 
     vectorscale}]], {time, 0, 2/50}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed

Comment: @vargss glad I could help, please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)